# GLib.Variant new empty array

Tags: python, glib

[Documentation](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/GLib-2.0/classes/Variant.html#GLib.Variant.new_array) says that `child_type must be non-None if n_children is zero`. So I can't get it. Where is the logic here? What type should I use for an empty array?
Here is my example code:

```
from gi.repository import GLib
child_type = None
child_value = None
result_value = GLib.Variant.new_array(child_type, child_value)
```

An here is the output:

```
./test.py:5: Warning: g_variant_new_array: assertion 'n_children > 0 || child_type != NULL' failed
  result_value = GLib.Variant.new_array(child_type, child_value)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 5, in <module>
    result_value = GLib.Variant.new_array(child_type, child_value)
TypeError: constructor returned NULL
```

When I create non-empty array - everything works fine. I can define child_type by type of child items. But with an empty array I stuck.

Have anyone any idea?

P.S. `child_value = []` doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What type should I use for an empty array?

The same type you’d use for a non-empty array. GVariant arrays are strongly typed, so an empty array of type `as` is semantically different from an empty array of type `au`. You need to specify the type of the elements which *would* be in the array were it not empty.

(More technically, the type of the array element actually makes a difference to the alignment requirements of the serialised form of the array, even if the array is empty. So it is a practical difference as well as a purely semantic one.)

Comment: Ok, now it works. Thanks a lot! May I ask another one question? What if I don't know the type of the future content of this array?

Comment: You need to know the type. You can’t create the array unless you know the type.

You can have an array with `v` (variant) type elements as the children, so the array type is `av`. That leaves the type resolution to runtime, but means that each child could be a different type from all the others, and all your code will have to handle children having any possible type.